# Yii2, как обработать с формы post массив данных для сохранения в бд?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем здрасте!

Есть Модель + у меня связь с таблицами.

Таблица profile && work_schedule

Есть такая таблица work_schedule, есть такие поля (внизу таблица), с формы я принимаю данные они должны записаться в work_schedule, и id от work_schedule должно записаться в в таблицу profile -> schedule_id. И я не могу понять как мне обработать саму форму, что бы принять Дни недели и время???

```
'id' => 1,
'week' => 'ПН',
'start_time' => '08.00',
'end_time' => '17.00',
'break_start' => '12.00',
'break_start' => '13.00',
'is_weekend' => false,
```

В Profile модели у меня хранится дни недели виде массива и публичные свойства,а также updateProfile(), где через контроллер принимаю и отправляю в модель.

```
class Profile extends ActiveRecord
```

{
    public $status_week;
    public $times;
    public $has_break;
    public $work_start;
    public $work_end;
    public $break_start;
    public $break_end;
    public $gallery;

```
public static function weeks()
{
    return [1 => 'ПН', 2 => 'ВТ', 3 => 'СР', 4 => 'ЧТ', 5 => 'ПТ', 6 => 'СБ', 7 => 'ВС'];
}
```

}

Сама форма в вьюхе

```
<?php foreach ($weeks as $k => $v) : ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

         <?= $form->field($model, "[$k]work_start")-
        >widget(TimePicker::classname(),
                        [
                            'value' => '00:00',
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'showMeridian' => false,
                            ]
                        ])->label('');
                    ?>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

В форме я раскладываю foreach, и получается что для каждого дня есть свое время и перерыв field($model, '[$k]work_start'), вот только я не могу понять как получить сам массив что бы сохранить в бд [$k]work_start - ПН|09:00, принимаю в контроллере и в модели происходит сам updateProfile.

делаю var_dump и получаю такой массив

```
[
'_csrf' => 'ajI4RHc0RUkeVgABH3kPej9CVSAaTXYgBn0VLTVlIiAhA3ocO2EfCw=='
'Profile' => [
    'status_week' => '1'
    ПН => [
        'work_start' => '09:00'
        'work_end' => '18:00'
        'break_start' => '12:00'
        'break_end' => '13:00'
    ]
    'has_break' => '1'
]
]
```

Comment: Если честно  , читаю по 3му разу, не могу связать нормально ваши предложения. Может вам стоит перечитать что вы написали , и слегка отредактировать. А кто как немец в попыхах))

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял у вас две таблицы . А значит у вас 2 модели. в главной моделе, вам необходим метод, который будет тянуть связь

```
public function getBlaBla()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Org::BlaBla(), ['id' => 'BlaBla']);
}
```

примерно так.
а в форме будет виртуальное свойство .

```
<?= $form->field($model->org0, 'name')->....
```

можно сделать иначе, через With

Но тут я перечитал последний абзац...

```
вот только я не могу понять как получить сам массив что бы сохранить в бд [$k]work_start - ПН|09:00,
```

если отвечать на этот вопрос . то массив будет тут

```
Yii::$app->request->post('Profile')
```

После метода load свойства модели будут заполнены из массива пост. а после $model->save()  - сохранены

Comment: если я правильно понял, я получаю такой пост $_POST['Profile']['work_start'], а потом его сохраняю, типа такого $work->work_start = $_POST['Profile']['work_start']; $model->save(false);

Comment: если у вас нет проблем с выводом нужных данных и т.п , а проблема понять куда прилетает и как сохранить, перехватить или что то сделать. то когда вы нажимаете отправить . Форма постом летит в метод. в yii обычно принимается так.if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { что то делаем }  первое условие говорит , загрузи в модель те данные которые пришли постом, вторая говорит , сохрани модель с валидацией.   / сделайте вардамп Yii::$app->request->post() после отправки формы на сохранение. и посмотрите что там будет

Comment: то есть так можно сделать??

Comment: мне совсем не ясно как у вас организовано все. но если вы сохраняете  в туже модель ,  ( наверно в сериализованном виде , иначе массив не сохраните) , то да

Comment: я понял вас.....если мне еще понадобиться ваша помощь, я могу к вам еще раз обратиться??

Comment: если я смогу чем то вам помочь, то всегда пожалуйста